# Libgdx: Remove white space in a sprite

Tags: libgdx

I recently started using Libgdx for the first time and I'm trying to make a 2D game similar to Zelda/Pokemon.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to make the sprite blend with the background (a tiled map .tmx file). I tried using enableBlending() but it doesn't work. I want the white space around the sprite to be removed so that the tiled map background shows.

[tiled map with the sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLur9.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blending is not required in your case.
Just use .png(having transparent background) file instead of .jpg(having white background).

[image]